# Inject property into non managed Spring xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, properties, ehcache

I am having xml. (Ehcache.xml)
I want to inject into it property from property file(on the classpath).

However since this xml is not a Spring managed bean I am not able to do so.

Any recommendations how to overcome this?

the xml:

```
...
            properties="peerDiscovery=manual,rmiUrls=//**${other.node.hostname}**:41001/org.jasig.cas.ticket.ServiceTicket|//**${other.node.hostname}**:41001/org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicket"
            propertySeparator="," />



    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
            properties="port=41001,socketTimeoutMillis=5000" />

</ehcache>
```

I want to inject **${other.node.hostname}** from another properties file.

but I get this on runtime:

Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 2: //**${other.node.hostname}**:41001/org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketGrantingTicket

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1):

in the ehcache.xml it won't work because it's not spring configuration. But if you define the equivalent configuration in spring instead of the ehcache file it should work:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>

<bean id="myCache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="${cache.maxMemoryElements}"/>
</bean>
```

the best is to use the ehcache.xml file the least possible and configure everything in spring, as most of the options in the file have a spring equivalent.

Comment: But how would you modify the new spring xml with those properties: cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory, cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory ?